# Disposing SQL command and closing the connection

Tags: c#, sql, dispose

till now I always used a similar structure to get data from DB and fill a DataTable

```
public static DataTable GetByID(int testID)
        {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM tbl_Test AS T WHERE T.testID = @testID";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DefaultConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@testID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = testID;

            cn.Open();
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Now I saw some warnings in the build analysis:

TestService.cs (37): CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'TestService.GetByID(int)', object 'table' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'table' before all references to it are out of scope.

TestService.cs (42): CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'TestService.GetByID(int)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'cmd' before all references to it are out of scope.

Should I change my code in

```
    public static DataTable GetByID(int testID)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM tbl_Test AS T WHERE T.testID = @testID";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DefaultConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@testID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = testID;

                cn.Open();
                table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        return table;
    }
```

What to do with DataTable object?
Is it a good practice to place SqlCommand inside the using?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: Yes. Your code is correct now. Always dispose the class implementing IDisposable. But is SqlDataReader also disposable?

Comment: Do you dispose the DataTable that you return?

Comment: I believe the reader is disposable yes, and perhaps that is the issue WRT the table not being disposed as it holds a reader which has not been explicitly close, although I expect it will have been closed implicitly when the cmd is disposed.

Comment: You should do something like this: using (SqlDataReader reader =
            command.ExecuteReader
                (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }

Comment: @Kangkan What do you mean dispose DataTable then return? I return that DataTable, I can't Dispose it there.

Comment: @MaiOM: I am talking about the DataTable that you return from this method. The idea is DataTable itself is to be disposed. So in the caller code, the DataTable should be disposed after use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also do this:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader =
            cmd.ExecuteReader
                (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            table.Load(reader);
        }
```

when loading the table

Comment: It is the first time that I see this approach. Why on MSDN nothing similar is even mentioned?

Comment: It's one option. MSDN shows only a sample(simple)case. And, yes you should dispose the datatable too.

Comment: Well as my are usually web applications, when should I call the disposal of the used DataTable? Lets say that on page load I associate that method call to the grid and Bind it. Where to call the dispose method? Thanks

Comment: If you use it with a datagrid or gridview, there is no good way to dispose it and you can leave it as it is. It's only if you're in another context(if datatable is not binded directly to a control) that you can dispose. Moreover it seems(google search) that there is no unmanaged resources in datatable though it implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 3):

- The caller of this method should call the dispose of the DataTable returned when it is done using it.
- Yes, it is a good practice to place SqlCommand inside using.

Comment: Well as my are usually web applications, when should I call the disposal of the used DataTable? Lets say that on page load I associate that method call to the grid and Bind it. Where to call the dispose method?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To "fix" your issue with the DataTable, perhaps you could modify your function.

```
public static void GetByID(DataTable table, int testID)
{
    // bla bla bla
}


// calling the function
using(DataTable table = new DataTable())
{
    TestService.GetByID(table, 5);
}
```

Not saying this is the optimal solution, but it will solve the complaint.